# How to send an email using PHP that includes youtube video

Tags: php, html, youtube

I have a php script that read a database and pull email addresses. For each email address I build a html scripts with header, images, button ,etc.  works fine.

I am trying to send using php in the email a youtube video also so the user can play the youtube in the email.  It seems all the other html elements are send but the iframe for the youtube is not showing.

Comment: What's the most popular video-capable email client in your experience?

Comment: Not all html work in an email viewer and not all email clients support every html. I have never seen a youtube video play in any of the major email clients. Best bet is to show the thumbnail with a click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded content can pose a great security threat so it is automatically blocked or not even supported by most mail clients and providers.

The only thing you can do is put a screenshot image of that YouTube video with the YouTube play button in the middle (just like the one below) and link it to the actual video on click.

[image]